# What is a most efficient way to implement Gantt Chart in Angular js application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, gantt-chart, angular-gantt

I am working on a Hotel Management application in which I am using Angular Gantt chart to manage rates of rooms. My hotel has large number of rooms and each room has different rate plans, so to manage all that in Angular Gantt chart is not possible. (loading large amount of data in a chart at once hangs the system.)

So, in order to manage that, I added lazy loading in it and loads only records for 10 days but it didn't solve my problem. So I again breaks the data and added a dropdown in Chart and displayed records only for one room. This time it worked fine as I loaded small amount of data in a chart but it is not what I am looking for.

So I want to know about the most efficient way to display maximum data in a chart or some other way to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No silver bullets to optimization really... if you can show your code running in a plnkr or jsfiddle with some sample data dumped/scrubbed of personal info (or generated online search for JSON generator) then can show the problem in action and can get others like me to take a look at the timeline and actual script execution to see why it's slow and what you could do to fix the library or to not build yourself into the same corner.  Something like D3.js can be used for advanced visualizations but for Gantt chart might be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Varun,

I would like to recommend our [RadiantQ jQuery Gantt Package](http://radiantq.com/products/jquery-gantt-package/jquery-gantt-package-features/). It's natively built to support a large number of "tasks" in the timeline. You don't even have to bother lazy load, our UI is virtualized and so can handle large data.

If you could give us an idea on how your data looks like, we can even put together a Proof Of Concept.